# Cellranger takes forever to run

Tags: bioinformatics

I'm new to the whole cellranger things as I'm more of a wet lab guy. I follow the cellranger tutorial on 10x Website https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/tutorial_ct#countsetup.

However, it seems like my slurm job takes forever to be completed as there is a step called "chunks_running" keeps repeating itself for around 150 times. My friend told me this pipeline should take only 5-6 hours to run.

[it took 5 hour to repeat itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioFyJ.png)
May I ask what is the problem here and how can I address it?
Thank you all.

I have read the slurm job log and look for the answer but so far I'm hopeless

Answer (score 1):

CellRanger is all but a speedster. These logs you see are normal. Generally it will take many hours depending on the size of your dataset and the allocated resources. You can disable all the (useless imo) secondary analysis (see the command line help for the exact flag to set) to speed it up a bit, or just wait until it is finished. The latter is what you should actually do. While annoying, it is reasonably robust and almost always finishes without errors, so just sit and wait.

5-6 hours is what you could expect with a lot of resources. For example, I just checked a run we did with about 6000 cells and 400mio reads, this took about 5:30h allowing 36 cores and 70GB of RAM on a decent HPC node.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. This is the first time I do it and I don't even know what to expect. I only use 1 core this time which makes everything seem reasonable.

Comment: Yes, with one core this can easily run "forever", this is expected then.